# Angular Typescript Directive with Isolate Scope generates Typescript errors on compile

Tags: angularjs, typescript, isolate-scope

I'm using Typescript and Angular, trying to make the site more accessible by using (among other things) the accessible icon directive below from [here](http://blog.shinetech.com/2014/11/26/getting-started-with-angular-and-accessibility/).

```
module app.directives {
    export class AccessibleIconDirective implements ng.IDirective {
        priority = 0;
        restrict = 'E';
        scope: { name: '@', text: '@'};
        template: '<i class="fa fa-{{name}}"></i><span class="invisible">{{text}}</span>';
    }
}
```

The Typescript compiler doesn't like the isolate scope, and gives me the following errors.

```
accessibleIcon.ts(5,24): error TS1110: Type expected.
accessibleIcon.ts(5,27): error TS1005: ';' expected.
accessibleIcon.ts(5,35): error TS1110: Type expected.
accessibleIcon.ts(8,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

I'm not sure how to give `name: '@'` and `text:'@'` a type in this structure, and I'm at a loss why TS wants a semicolon within the scope object, or a Declaration after the module.

I'm implementing the ng.IDirective interface, so I would expect it to be able to deal with an isolate scope.

Any ideas? Thanks!

For reference, here's the IDirective interface in angular.d.ts:

```
interface IDirective {
    compile?: IDirectiveCompileFn;
    controller?: any;
    controllerAs?: string;
    bindToController?: boolean|Object;
    link?: IDirectiveLinkFn | IDirectivePrePost;
    name?: string;
    priority?: number;
    replace?: boolean;
    require?: any;
    restrict?: string;
    scope?: any;
    template?: any;
    templateNamespace?: string;
    templateUrl?: any;
    terminal?: boolean;
    transclude?: any;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `:` when you should be using `=`. These are supposed to be property initializers, not type annotations.

```
module app.directives {
    export class AccessibleIconDirective implements ng.IDirective {
        priority = 0;
        restrict = 'E';
        // fixed
        scope = { name: '@', text: '@'};
        // fixed
        template = '<i class="fa fa-{{name}}"></i><span class="invisible">{{text}}</span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: All I have to say is "D'oh!" And "thanks." Couldn't see the forest for the using 3 frameworks trees